# How to create 50000 tcp connection in single linux machine?

Tags: java, linux, sockets, tcp

I tried to create 50000 tcp connection in single linux machine but i was not able to create 50000 connections only 10800 tcp connections were created.after that i got java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread.

I changed 
 `ulimit -n 200000, nproc in /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf,`
  /etc/sysctl.conf`sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_mem='8388608 8388608 8388608'
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_rmem='4096 87380 8388608'
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_wmem='4096 65536 8388608`

I changed statck size to `ulimit -s 100000`
  Help me to create 50000 tcp connections in single linux machine

Comment: Check http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-monitoring/how-to-solve-javalangoutofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread

Comment: Are you using threads for the connections? One thread per connection? That is a really bad idea for so many connections, the computer and operating system will do will be swapping between the threads, no real work would be done.

Comment: yes i am using thread per connection. okay can you guide me step by step to create max tcp connections in single linux  machine? what are all the configuration i have to change?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Independently from your `OutOfMemoryError`, which can be solved with more memory, each socket in Linux is actually a file descriptor, and a given process cannot have 50k open file descriptors.

Comment: Isn't the max limit supposed to be `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`? (If it's not overridden by ulimit)

Comment: I got a point from few websites that 65535 tcp connections  are possible in a machine.Then why it is not possible to create 50k connections.where i have to make changes ?  What are the OS level and memory level configurations to create maximum tcp connections with out any memory error? can you guide me step by step

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani When I tested I was able to create around 3-4k connections until I got an `IOException` about file descriptors. My `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` is set to 793911.

Comment: @mohanrajvcbe Theoretically, you can create 65535 simultaneous connections (per network interface). About the OOM error, you need to set more memory to the JVM.

Comment: @m0skit0 Argument against "a process cannot have more than 50k open file handles": https://gist.github.com/nehaljwani/034bbd8ba6dd9282c82a05e5150bf9b4

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani Nice. Did you actually try it? I did: `$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
793911
$ perl test.pl             
 FDs: 1021 Too many open files at test.pl line 8.`

Comment: @m0skit0 As I said before, you need to remove the limit overridden by ulimit. I have shown that it in the gist. Yes, I tried it before putting it up in the gist. I spawned a virtual machine running Fedora 24.

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani `$ ulimit -n 99354
ulimit: value exceeds hard limit`

Comment: @m0skit0 Also notice that I am root in the gist. For users, it might be set in `/etc/security/limits.conf` or some files in `/etc/security/limits.d/*.conf`

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani `/etc/security/limits.conf` is fully commented. No files under `/etc/security/limits.d/`

Comment: @m0skit0  Are you root? Also: http://serverfault.com/a/485277/140905 There was another patch to control limits on open file handles by using cgroups. Dunno if the patch was accepted in the linux kernel. lwn.net/Articles/604129

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani No, I'm not root. Then the limits must be hardcoded on the kernel compilation itself. I'm not sure recompiling the kernel is a valid solution for OP. Btw thanks for all the info, very informative.